# typescript: props provided by redux connect are an intersection that doesn't allow access to actions

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I have a container that I want to connect to the redux store using redux connect function. The connect function typings seems to be able to determine the resulting props, but If I try to access the inferred props on the wrapped component I get typescript errors telling me that not the mapped actions nor the stats state are present on the intersection type connect generates:

```
Property 'actions' does not exist on type 'PropsWithChildren<Matching<{ stats: { getSessionsPending: boolean; getSessionsError: null; }; } & { actions: { setupApp: () => (dispatch: any, getState: any) => Promise<void>; getSessions: () => GetSessionThunk; dismissGetSessionsError: () => { ...; }; }; }, Matching<...> | (ClassAttributes<...> & Matching<...>)>>'.
  Property 'actions' does not exist on type 'Matching<{ stats: { getSessionsPending: boolean; getSessionsError: null; }; } & { actions: { setupApp: () => (dispatch: any, getState: any) => Promise<void>; getSessions: () => GetSessionThunk; dismissGetSessionsError: () => { ...; }; }; }, Matching<...>> & { ...; }
```

This is a small reproduction example with a [link to a typescript playground:](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=27&ssc=27&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgKIBmZSGcAvnGVBCHAORSoYsDcAsAFChIsXHDQQAduKrw6DJq3boYAWnYATfAA9u-MeMLxiMfGACCYMHAC8cABQBKawD47OGAE8wSAFysjJ5QgAaxYae10JAzgAERRCAAsAIwgUKDVrO0crFwAeNWAANycACSQAGzKIHIB6fKL%20fjJ8cQxgCTgQFDAAZRgUGCQAFQgABUYwQlsDfp8caZhCXxRxdzDcfjg4dmMocXW%20Tc35xbh5pAA6Y8wN2l4%20Gga%20PSjOsGjgQjB%20tHjhsYgJhkcDclG19L48P4zBZaNd7ncIvp4HopBhoBkUdJbK9ejM-uNCNhXu9Pt9fqMCfYEU9IvBokgyCh8GUYCMUABzJAYiSomDQWxgAnOfabIikChYhzC4EHQ7PeCQpDGaFgbCcmDdJCEQhgwi0DKCgGEc6gyJ3Q6nJUmcxgBznGDxJDiWzqzXa3VUm40bAAbQAup7ZfKRMR3ZF9TZDRNLn0FuatlbdnAcrEEslUulQzrIlY5lrs-o6NUnHcwtSkJohPA1AymSyYrXmayOUggA)

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
const setupApp = () => ({type: 'setup-ok'})
const Dashboard = () => <div>Hello</div>

function mapStateToProps(state:{stats: any}) {
  return {
    stats: state.stats,
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  actions: { setupApp },
};

const connector = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);

const DefaultPage = connector(props => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const { setupApp, getSessions } = props.actions;
    setupApp().then(getSessions);
  }, []);
  const { sessions } = props.stats;
  return <Dashboard sessions={sessions} />;
});

export default DefaultPage
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `mapDispatch` here is actually incorrect and broken.

[`mapDispatch` can either be an object containing action creators, or a function that receives `dispatch` as an argument](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch).  What you have there is neither of those - it's an object that has a *nested* object containing action creators, and that will not be handled correctly.

So, you either need to switch to doing `const mapDispatch = {setupApp}` and drop the `actions` nesting, or you need to write `mapDispatch` as a function and handle setting up the `setupApp` prop yourself.

You're right that [we do recommend using the `ConnectedProps<T>` approach if you're using `connect` with TypeScript](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/static-typing#typing-the-connect-higher-order-component).  However, [**we recommend using the React-Redux hooks API as the default today instead of `connect`**](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks), and one of the reasons is that it's way easier to use that with TS.

All that could be simplified down to:

```js
const DefaultPage = () => {
  const stats= useSelector( (state: RootState) => state.stats);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(setupApp());
  }, [dispatch])
}
```

Comment: You're completely right, my actions were not properly binding. That explains why typescript was telling me that the  ThunkAction promise didn't have a then method, because it was not the correct thing (and I was blaming it for that...). This is a mistake I made while migrating from a function that was performing the binding to a plain object, and seems I stopped right in the middle. Thank you very much!

Comment: About using useDispatch and all that, I agree that it will be much nicer, but I am gradually converting an old app

Answer (score 0):

It seems that, for some reason, the types of the connect function doesn't play very well with actually passing a function taking the arguments it provides (don't ask me why)

However, it is possible to use the connector function (which is a bit alien to normal redux developers) to infer it's props type using a helper type from redux `ConnectedProps` so all you have to do is type your params as the result of applying `ConnectedProps` to your connector function:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { connect, ConnectedProps } from 'react-redux';
const setupApp = () => ({type: 'setup-ok'})
const Dashboard = () => <div>Hello</div>

function mapStateToProps(state:{stats: any}) {
  return {
    stats: state.stats,
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  actions: { setupApp },
};

const connector = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);

const DefaultPage = (props: ConnectedProps<typeof connector>) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const { setupApp } = props.actions;
    setupApp()
  }, []);
  const { sessions } = props.stats;
  return <Dashboard sessions={sessions} />;
}

export default connector(DefaultPage)
```